# NameError: name 'self' is not defined?

Tags: python, nameerror

I am currently working on python programming.

```
class A:
    def LoadPosition(self):
        FILE = open('a.txt', "r+")

        i = 0
        for node in self.nodes:
            line = FILE.readline()
            if i == 0:
                scaling_factor == float(line)
                i += 1
            else:
                tmpn, tmpx, tmpy, tmpa = line.split('\t')
                node.id = tmpn
                node.coordinate_x = float(tmpx)
                node.coordinate_y = float(tmpy)
                node.area = int(tmpa)
        FILE.close()
```

It was fine before, but all of sudden, it shows the NameError message. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the same indentation in your original code? It seems that is the problem. You need to indent all the code in your function by `4 spaces` to the right.

Comment: @RohitJain: he can't. That would be `IndentationError: Unexpected unindent`

Comment: @A.R.S.: look at the line after `def …`

Comment: @A.R.S. it was class, but thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Rohit Jain the indent was fine. When I copy the code, the indent was changed. I will modify it. Thanks. :)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget.. Yeah you are right. SangChae. Well, the problem does not seem to be in the posted code. Can you post the code where you are instatiating the class, and invoking the method?

Comment: Show the whole error, including traceback. Without that, you're asking us to analyse your code afresh.

Comment: @Marcin Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spring.py", line 144, in <module>
    class Graph:
  File "spring.py", line 317, in Graph
    for node in self.nodes:
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: @dm03514 It runs on python 2.7

Comment: @SangChae Put it in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing spaces and tabs in strange ways, which is probably confusing Python.  Here's what I get when I copy-and-paste your code from the edit window:

```
In [2]: for line in s.splitlines():
   ...:     print repr(line)
   ...:     
''
'    class A:'
'    \tdef LoadPosition(self):'
'\t        FILE = open(\'a.txt\', "r+")'
'    \t'
'\t\t    i = 0'
'    \t    for node in self.nodes:'
'    \t    \tline = FILE.readline()'
'    \t    \tif i == 0:'
'    \t    \t\tscaling_factor == float(line)'
'    \t    \t\ti += 1'
'    \t    \telse:'
"    \t    \t\ttmpn, tmpx, tmpy, tmpa = line.split('\t')"
'\t       \t     \tnode.id = tmpn'
'   \t\t         \tnode.coordinate_x = float(tmpx)'
'   \t\t         \tnode.coordinate_y = float(tmpy)'
'   \t\t     \t    node.area = int(tmpa)'
'\t\t    FILE.close()'
```

[Note that if someone copies code from the posted question and not the raw edit window, this might not happen -- at least sometimes it's suppressed seeing the original tabs for me -- and so people who try your code might not have any problems.]

Step #1: run your code using `python -tt yourfilenamehere.py` to confirm that it's a tab error.

Step #2: switch to using four-space tabs everywhere.

Comment: original code was fine, but thanks.

Comment: @SangChae: are you saying that the original code survived `python -tt`?

Comment: oh, my bad. Your comment was right. It was very helpful! Thank you.